# how make columns of dataframe variable

Tags: python

I want to make the columns of Salary_Data_split variables, depending of Sal_name (type : list) where:

```
Sal_name = ['Success_S_1', 'Failure_S_1', 'Success_S_2', 'Failure_S_2','Success_S_4', 'Failure_S_4','Success_S_7', 'Failure_S_7','Success_S_8', 'Failure_S_8']
```

and Salary_Data_split must be as follow, it contains: Salary + existing rows on Sal_name. Like :

```
Salary_Data_split = data[["Salary",'Success_S_1', 'Failure_S_1', 'Success_S_2', 'Failure_S_2','Success_S_4', 'Failure_S_4','Success_S_7', 'Failure_S_7','Success_S_8', 'Failure_S_8']]
```

I have tried this code but it doesnt work

```
Salary_Data_split = data[["Salary", Sal_name]]
```

Comment: Please explain what is your desired output.

Comment: Add quotation marks for `Sal_name`. Your syntax is correct otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Please *always include example* data in your posts.  It's also important to *always include error messages* in your posts. That way, your question is alot more clear. I am guessing `data` is your dataframe with columns `Sal_name` and `Salary`, which you want to combine in `Sal_data_split`?

```py
data['sal_Data_Split'] = [data['Salary'], data['Sal_name']]
```

This will put the columns `Salary` and `Sal_name` in a list, resulting in a nested list if `data['Sal_name']` is a list itself. The way you assigned `Salary_Data_split = data[["Salary", Sal_name]]` in your original post it just indexes 2 columns of the dataframe at once. You also forgot the quotation marks around `Sal_name` if that is what you meant.